# How can I give capabilities from command line in protractor?

Tags: protractor, browserstack

I want to give capabilities as cmd arguments. Capabilities has properties like *browserstack.key*, *browserstack.user*, etc. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Most configurations you can send to Protractor via the command line. The spelling for these can be found in the [config.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L141).

```
protractor /path/to/your/conf.js --browserstackKey {the browserstack key} --browserstackUser {the browser stack user}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @cnishina I tried this but it still giving me the error,"Authorization required". Path to config file i m not giving considering that it automatically takes default file. But that shoudn't be the reason of failing. right?

Comment: So I'd revise your question, show the error. This is as good of an answer that can be provided with the question / information provided. Is there a stack trace? Does your test work if you use a local standalone server?

Comment: I did it in different way...using stream editor command.Thanks for helping me.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: I wrote this on conf file->
 capabilities: {
    'browserstack.user': '{{browserstackUser}}',
    'browserstack.key': '{{browserstackKey}}'
  },
and ran this command to change the text in file ->
sed -i 's/{{browserstackUser}}/"browserstackuser"/g' protractor.conf.js